# Stripe Payments to handle Negative Payments

Tags: python, reactjs, stripe-payments, sanic, strawberry-graphql

Title: Handling Negative Payments in Stripe for Retainer Payments

Question:
I am currently integrating Stripe into my payment system, where I accept payments from customers online. Additionally, I also collect retainer payments from clients in cash. My goal is to handle negative payments when the retainer amount exceeds the actual order price. For instance, if a client pays a $20 retainer for a $10 order, I need to refund the $10 excess to the customer.

I've reviewed the documentation provided by Stripe, but I haven't found a solution that fully addresses this scenario.

Could someone please advise on the available approaches or best practices for handling negative payments in Stripe when dealing with retainer payments? Any insights, code examples, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds more like a Stripe product question and their support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) should be better placed to advise you on the available options.

Comment: You are looking for [refund](https://support.stripe.com/questions/refund-a-customer). Moreover, refund only works for payments made through the Stripe (or heck, any similar payment networks), and it's unlikely to work for the general case otherwise you can run quickly into all sorts of issues if this is generally allowed, up to and including fraud/AML. You should simply pay your clients back the excess cash if they gave you excess cash, or issue a partial refund if they made the payment in full via Stripe - anything mixed in between you will have to work out with your client.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.